# Python's pyautoGUI library and Microsoft Word

Tags: pyautogui

I need help with Python's pyautoGUI library.
I am creating a robot to copy articles from microsoft word to Wordpress.
I am having problems because each part of the word file goes to different fields of Wordpress, for example: I have texts in word to be placed in the fields of keywords, title, SEO description ... etc, within Wordpress. I don't know how to tell pyautoGUI where to start copying and where to finish copying text so i can paste it into Wordpress.
Can you help me, please?
Thanks

Comment: Can you share what you've done so far?

Answer (score 0):

This code may solve your problem. But you have to make sure that if you press Alt-Tab on the article window, the Wordpress window will appear. Do that and this code will work:

```
from pyautogui import *

hotkey("ctrl", "a")
hotkey("ctrl", "c")
hotkey("alt", "tab")
hotkey("ctrl", "v")
```